# Samba won't install because of broken packages

Tags: server, apt, package-management, samba, dependencies

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 and I didn't install Samba with the original OS setup. I would like to install it now, but I keep getting a error about broken packages. It appears that the main hangup is the `samba-libs` dependency. It says:

```
Depends: libldb1 (< 1:1.1.25~) but 2:1.1.17-2 is to be installed
```

But I already have the latest `libldb1` installed. I've tried almost everything I can google, but maybe I'm overlooking something. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Here's whats happening:

```
root@MAILSVR:/etc/apt# sudo apt-get  install  samba
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  samba : Depends: python-samba but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.3.8+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.3.8+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: samba-dsdb-modules but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not going to be installed 
         E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here's what `aptitude` gives me:

```
root@MAILSVR:/etc/apt# aptitude install samba

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libwbclient0{a} python-crypto{a} python-ldb{ab} python-samba{a} python-talloc{a} python-tdb{ab} samba samba-common{a} samba-common-bin{a} samba-dsdb-modules{a} 
  samba-libs{ab} samba-vfs-modules{a} tdb-tools{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,519 kB of archives. After unpacking 48.3 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-tdb : Depends: libtdb1 (= 1.3.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but 1.3.8-2 is installed.
 samba-libs : Depends: libldb1 (< 1:1.1.25~) but 2:1.1.17-2 is installed.
 python-ldb : Depends: libldb1 (= 1:1.1.24-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but 2:1.1.17-2 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:


     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     python-ldb [Not Installed]                         
2)     python-samba [Not Installed]                       
3)     python-tdb [Not Installed]                         
4)     samba [Not Installed]                              
5)     samba-common-bin [Not Installed]                   
6)     samba-dsdb-modules [Not Installed]                 
7)     samba-libs [Not Installed]                         
8)     samba-vfs-modules [Not Installed]                  


     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
9)     samba-common recommends samba-common-bin           




Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

`samba-libs` error:

```
root@MAILSVR:/etc/apt# apt-get install samba-libs
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:


The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 samba-libs : Depends: libldb1 (< 1:1.1.25~) but 2:1.1.17-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: You  can try running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` then running `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` see what errors  if any you get  .. you can add them to your question .. may point us in a direction to start looking

Comment: I tried that and I didn't get any errors.. I'm still getting the same errors when I try to install samba. While looking for a solution I came across [this thread](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin/issues/11) where some people are having a similar issue with samba-libs. Maybe it's a widespread issue..

Comment: you could force it `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/name_of_samba.deb` Then after run `sudo apt-get install -f` to see if there are any errors. not sure if this would work and if you would also have to force install samba-libs and or samba-common

Comment: This is all I have in that dir  `root@MAILSVR:/var/cache/apt/archives# ls
libssl1.0.0_1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb  libtasn1-6_3.4-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  lock  openssl_1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb  partial`

Comment: sorry to say I'm out of ideas .. hopefully someone else will  figure out a  way for you :(

Comment: The issue was with my package sources so I changed my /etc/apt/sources.list back to default with the help of [repogen.simplylinux.ch](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch)

Then I did a 
`apt-get autoremove libtdb1 --purge`

and then 
`apt-get install samba`

Done. Thx for your assistance!

Comment: lol well I didn't solve it but at least you worked it out .. glad to hear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was with my package sources so I changed my /etc/apt/sources.list back to default with the help of [repogen.simplylinux.ch](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch)

Then I ran these commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get autoremove libtdb1 --purge
apt-get install libtdb1=1.3.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
apt-get install samba
```

Done. Thx for your assistance!

Comment: Mark your answer with green mark on the left side, it helps to identify a successfully answer!

Comment: You could try pressing `.` dot on aptitude, it suggests modifications scheme for desired packaging.

Comment: Sry I'm new here.. Thx for the pointers!

Answer (score 2):

The following command helped me to install samba over Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS:

```
sudo aptitude install samba
```

Output:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  attr{a} ibverbs-providers{a} libcephfs2{a} libibverbs1{a} libldb1{a} 
  libnl-route-3-200{a} librados2{a} libtdb1{a} python-crypto{a} 
  python-dnspython{a} python-ldb{a} python-samba{a} python-tdb{a} samba 
  samba-common{a} samba-common-bin{a} samba-dsdb-modules{ab} samba-libs{ab} 
  samba-vfs-modules{a} tdb-tools{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 20 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.1 MB of archives. After unpacking 70.7 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 samba-dsdb-modules : Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2) but 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.9 is installed
 samba-libs : Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2) but 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.9 is installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     python-samba [Not Installed]                       
2)     samba [Not Installed]                              
3)     samba-common-bin [Not Installed]                   
4)     samba-dsdb-modules [Not Installed]                 
5)     samba-libs [Not Installed]                         
6)     samba-vfs-modules [Not Installed]                  

Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
7)     samba recommends samba-dsdb-modules                
8)     samba-common recommends samba-common-bin           

    Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n


The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Downgrade the following packages:                                          
1)     libwbclient0 [2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.9 (now) -> 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu



    Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libwbclient0 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  attr{a} ibverbs-providers{a} libcephfs2{a} libibverbs1{a} libldb1{a} 
  libnl-route-3-200{a} librados2{a} libtdb1{a} python-crypto{a} 
  python-dnspython{a} python-ldb{a} python-samba{a} python-tdb{a} samba 
  samba-common{a} samba-common-bin{a} samba-dsdb-modules{a} samba-libs{a} 
  samba-vfs-modules{a} tdb-tools{a} 
.......

    samba


[2019/07/11 12:31:24.139070,  0] ../lib/util/debug.c:1053(reopen_logs_internal)
  Unable to open new log file '/var/log/samba/log.%m': Permission denied
[2019/07/11 12:31:24.139119,  0] ../source4/smbd/server.c:448(binary_smbd_main)
  samba version 4.7.6-Ubuntu started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2017
```

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me on Ubuntu Server 16.04.1, but none of the previous replies worked for me. After searching for the solution for many hours I got this one to work properly:

```
sudo wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/109052632/python-support_1.0.15_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-support_1.0.15_all.deb
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by this:

```
sudo apt-get install libwbclient0=2:4.3.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 &&
sudo apt-get install samba
```