# Repair Ubuntu System on a Mac Pro 2007

Tags: grub2, moklistrt

When I was trying to install samba, I had some issue that I tried to fix according to this forum thread. I'm running ubuntu 20.04.

[Samba won't install because of broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767594/samba-wont-install-because-of-broken-packages)

I ran the commands

```
apt-get update
apt-get autoremove libtdb1 --purge
apt-get install libtdb1=1.3.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
apt-get install samba
```

after running apt-get autoremove libtdb1 --purge, I was a bit concerned as I saw a lot of seemingly paramount packages were listed as being removed.

after running `apt-get install libtdb1=1.3.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1`, it returned something like "package already installed".

After rebooting, my machine started checking filesystems, once complete, it got stuck on a screen saying "/dev/sda6: clean, ###/### files, ###/### blocks". I was able to open a shell with ctrl+alt+f2, and I can run commands and see all my files etc. However, I was unable to test fixes (mostly aimed at installing some packages) as I seem not to be connected to the internet.

I figured that I must have uninstalled some important packages for booting in ubuntu desktop. So I thought I have to reinstall using a new bootable usb. I stuck in a fresh usb with ubuntu 20.04 bootable iso. However, when trying to boot from it, I get the error:

Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter

Could not create mokListRT: Invalid Parameter

Importing MOK states has failed: import_mok_state() failed: Invalid Parameter

Continuing boot since secure mode is disabled.

I tried the most upvoted solution on a threat I found, namely:

```
sudo su -
cd /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
cp grubx64.efi shimx64.efi
reboot
```

This didn't fix the problem.

I seem to be stuck between a rock and a hard place. If there was a way of running my booted usb through the shell I can open on my normal broken boot, but I don't have the faintest idea how. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279602/ubuntu-20-04-failed-to-set-moklistrt-invalid-parameter)

Comment: No, sorry. That's the one I tried already.