# Unable to Install Samba on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: samba

I have upgraded Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 23.10 LTS, I have tried to install **Samba** but I'm having a problem could you please help me to resolve it?

```
root@13566C-UDHAYAKUMAR:~# sudo apt install samba
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 samba : Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.18.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 2:4.18.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
         Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.18.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: attr
         Recommends: python3-markdown but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: samba-dsdb-modules but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: samba-ad-provision but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried after as per this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767594/samba-wont-install-because-of-broken-packages) below as well but it is not working. Also, I have tried `sudo apt install nautilus-share` but this also gives the same error.

Comment: You mention on upgrade from 22.04 to 23.10; is this correct? as that currently is an *unsupported* upgrade path; (22.04 currently only upgrades to 23.04 or the next non-LTS).  The correct package expected for 23.10 or *mantic* is `samba-common | 2:4.18.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1        | mantic-security | all` so I'd check your sources are correct  (ie. `sudo apt update` & check all lines are present, none missing, no warnings etc - or check sources).  Your mentioned upgrade though highlights missing details or you're using a currently *unsupported* upgrade which is open currently only for QA.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 is **not** a LTS release; it's the last of the non-LTS in the two-year development cycle which completes with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS April next year. All of 22.10, 23.04, 23.10 & 24.04 make up the current *development* cycle (*with the last only being the long-term-support release*)
.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)